# How to send a message every x minutes?

Tags: python, discord.py

```
fotddict = {}
 
@client.event
async def on_ready():
  global fotddict
  with open("factoftheday.json", "r") as f:
      fotddict = json.load(f)
 
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def fotd(ctx, channel : discord.TextChannel=None):
 
  if channel is None:
    embe=discord.Embed(title="<:redcross:781952086454960138>Error", description="**Please pass in all required arguments!**\nNeed help?** https://dsc.gg/otaysupport**", color=0x7289da)
    await ctx.send(embed=embe)
  
  else:
    #are you sure embed
    msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
 
    def checkifnotbotfact(reaction, user):
        return user != client.user
 
    await msg.add_reaction('')
 
    reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout=60.0, check=checkifnotbotfact)
 
    if str(reaction.emoji) == "": 
      
    #confirm embed
 
      global fotddict
      fotddict[str(ctx.guild.id)] = channel.id
 
      with open("factoftheday.json", "w") as f:
          json.dump(fotddict, f)
 
@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def factsend(member):
    x = randfacts.getFact()
    channel_id = fotddict[str(member.guild.id)]
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Fact of the day!", description=x, color=0x7289da)
    await client.get_channel(channel_id).send(embed=embed)
 
@factsend.before_loop
async def before():
  factsend.start()
  await client.wait_until_ready()
```

**Problem:** This is my fact of the day command, it adds the channel id + guild id in a json file (so that isnt the problem). I think the problem is the loop, since that is the part that im not sure of if thats correct.

**Goal:** Bot sends a message with a fact every 24 hours (Task is set to 10 seconds for test purposes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly your `@factsend.before_loop` function is called just before the loop execution, so you have to start the loop in other place, not in the function. So you have to deplace `factsend.start()` outside of this function.

The corriged code will be:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
  global fotddict
  with open("factoftheday.json", "r") as f:
      fotddict = json.load(f)
 
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def fotd(ctx, channel : discord.TextChannel=None):
 
  if channel is None:
    embe=discord.Embed(title="<:redcross:781952086454960138>Error", description="**Please pass in all required arguments!**\nNeed help?** https://dsc.gg/otaysupport**", color=0x7289da)
    await ctx.send(embed=embe)
  
  else:
    #are you sure embed
    msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
 
    def checkifnotbotfact(reaction, user):
        return user != client.user
 
    await msg.add_reaction('')
 
    reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout=60.0, check=checkifnotbotfact)
 
    if str(reaction.emoji) == "": 
      
    #confirm embed
 
      global fotddict
      fotddict[str(ctx.guild.id)] = channel.id
 
      with open("factoftheday.json", "w") as f:
          json.dump(fotddict, f)
 
@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def factsend(member):
    x = randfacts.getFact()
    channel_id = fotddict[str(member.guild.id)]
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Fact of the day!", description=x, color=0x7289da)
    await client.get_channel(channel_id).send(embed=embed)
 
@factsend.before_loop
async def before():
  await client.wait_until_ready()

factsend.start() #deplaced outside of the function
```

Have a nice day!

Comment: Thank you very much, 1 question. If i restart the bot the timer will “reset” right?

Comment: in my opinion, yes

Answer (score -1):

If you are going to leave the bot running locally (or host it somewhere), then you should use [Advance Python Scheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

#Code goes Here

scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(function_name_you_want_to_run(), 'interval', hours=24)
scheduler.start()
```

Comment: Sorry but discord.py have an integrated system for that which work fine

Comment: This is bad, really bad. This whole code it's blocking (even the name itself says it), you should **NEVER** use blocking functions within an asynchronous code, it defeats the whole purpose of it.